# How do prevent videos from starting playing themselves right after clicking on them?

Tags: youtube, safari

Sometimes I need to go to a video just to check its description and not to watch the video. Those times I am frequently bothered by the automatic play of the video, which often happens to start with an ad. Is there an option in the YouTube settings to prevent that? (a Safari extension would also do the trick)

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/stop-autoplay-videos-ibrw29c6ecf8/mac

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well. If not, let us know so we can work on it. After all, you **did draw attention** with your bounty. Shame to waste it.

Answer (score 2):

You mention:

> a Safari extension would also do the trick

There is now an option in Safari to choose per site.
You do **not** need an extension.
You need to take the action just once.

Please try the following:

1. go to `Safari`
2. click on `Settings for This Website...`
3. on the pop-up choose `Stop Media with Sound`

*(**DO make sure you are on `youtube.com`** and NOT on the specific video)*

[image]

You should finally have this:

[image]

Comment: This almost does the trick. Using this, I can stop the auto-play whenever I open the videos in new tabs in the background. When I go to the previously created new tab, the video does not auto-play. However, whenever I do not use tabs but instead left-click on the video thumbnail, the video auto-plays once the website has loaded.

Comment: Please have a look at [this alternative](https://mymobotips.com/stop-autoplay-video-in-safari-for-mac/) (worked on my end - macos Big Sur).  I can then add it to the answer.

Comment: Sorry we could not find a better solution for you